# what is the best way to select row and view its details in new div

Tags: angularjs

I have components, **project** and **document**
the project has some fields and some documents.

[image]

I have **controller.js** and **service.js** for **projects** , **controller.js** and **service.js** for **documents**

I don't use `$scope` at all in my application

what I want to do is when I select a row to display it's documents

I use this function in document `controller` to get the documents

```
 documentCtrl.callServer = function callServer(projectId) {
     return documentsService.getDocuments(projectId).then(
             function(result) {
                 documentCtrl.displayed = result.documents;
             });
 }
```

I display the `documentCtrl.displayed` in document table

and use this function in project controller to select a row

```
 projectCtrl.toggleSelection = function indexof(row){
                                 projectCtrl.ViewMode = 1;
                                 projectCtrl.showViewProjectPanel(row);
                                 projectCtrl.selectionRow = row;
                                 $scope.passSelectionRow = row;
 }
```

as you can see I tried to call the `document` function from inside my project `controller` but it didn't work.

I tried to solve the problem just like that

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped"
            st-pipe="doc.callServer(proj.selectionRow.projectId  )" st-table="doc.displayed"
            st-safe-src="doc.rowCollection">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th  class="col-sm-1 grid_header" layout-align="center center" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: bottom;"><md-checkbox   aria-label="1"></th>
                    <th class="col-sm-1 grid_header" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><font size="3" color="#ffffff" >document Name</font></th>
                    <th class="col-sm-1 grid_header" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><font size="3" color="#ffffff" >Description</font></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="row in doc.displayed" ng-class="{selected : row.documentId == doc.selectedRowId}">
                        <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; margin: auto;"><md-checkbox  ng-checked="doc.isSelected(row.documentId)" ng-click="doc.toggleSelection(row)"></md-checkbox>

                        <td style="display: none;">{{row.documentId}}</td>
                            <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">{{row.documentName}}</td>
                            <td class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">{{row.documentExtension}}</td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

to pass the projectId to the function that build the document table but it gave me this error

: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":{},"oldVal":{}}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":{},"oldVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":{},"oldVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":{},"oldVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":{},"oldVal":"..."}]]

Comment: *I don't use $scope at all in my application* that's part of the problem.

Comment: I have many modules and I prefer not to use scope

Comment: ProjectComponent::&onProjectSelect. Then DetailsComponent can be either smart (load details by projectId ($onChanges)), DetailsComponent<projectId. Or it can be dumb (take details from parent component), DetailsComponent<projectDetails.

Comment: please read my answer and if you can explain more please @dfsq

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) and multiple named views. [Sample app](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts) is doing exactly what you want.

Comment: I didn't understand how can I use ui-router to solve my problem

Comment: In sample app is a list of elements and details of element after click. Look at it, read documentation.